# Cisco Catalyst 3560G telnet access

Tags: networking, cisco

I currently have telnet access to switch.

interface Vlan2

ip address 172.17.0.7 255.255.255.0
!

ip default-gateway 172.17.0.1
ip classless

access-list 160 permit ip host 172.17.0.101 any

line vty 0 4

access-class 160 in

timeout login response 240

...

login authentication vty

I want to move this switch to a dedicated management network 192.168.254.0

interface Vlan254
 ip address 192.168.254.2 255.255.255.0
!
ip default-gateway 192.168.254.1

I can ping 192.168.254.1 and 192.168.254.2, however I cannot telnet to 192.168.254.2
Firewall is currently allowing full IP between 172.17.0.0 and 192.168.254.0.  I will tighten this at a later date.

Can somebody point me in the correct direction?

Comment: What is the source IP of your telnet traffic?  You have an access class restricting the source to only 172.17.0.101/32

Comment: source ip is 172.17.0.101

Answer (score 0):

Feels like asymmetric routing, but I can't understand your topology well enough from the description.  It sounds like you're directly attached to this switch on the 172.17.0/24 network, but clearly there is a 192.168.254.0/24 network also attached to the switch in some way.  And there is apparently a firewall somewhere, but ...

A couple ideas off the top of my head:

Try using ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.254.1 instead of the default gateway command.  default gateway only does something when the switch is not routing.  By creating two vlan interfaces you may be implicitly routing.

Are you replacing VLAN 2 with VLAN 254, or adding VLAN 254 on to the switch?  What is the output of show ip route on the switch?

Comment: Default gateway is 192.168.254.1

Host               Gateway           Last Use    Total Uses  Interface
ICMP redirect cache is empty

Comment: I am looking to replace vlan2 with vlan254

Comment: You can ping 192.168.1.1 and .2 from your desktop @ 172.17.0.101?